# How to call thymeleaf custom dialect in html script

Tags: java, html, json, thymeleaf, schema.org

So basically I try to build a dynamic schema with ld+json by using thymeleaf. To retrieve the url for the corresponding page we set up a custom processor with:

```
public class QuackUrlAttributeTagProcessor extends AbstractAttributeTagProcessor {
    private static final String ATTR_NAME = "quackToHref";
    private static final int PRECEDENCE = 10000;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationPropertyAccess applicationProperties;

    /**
     * Constructs a new processor.
     *
     * @param dialectPrefix the prefix to use if not the standard defined by the dialect
     */
    public QuackUrlAttributeTagProcessor(final String dialectPrefix) {
        super(
            TemplateMode.HTML, // This processor will apply only to HTML mode
            dialectPrefix,     // Prefix to be applied to name for matching
            null,              // No tag name: match any tag name
            false,             // No prefix to be applied to tag name
            ATTR_NAME,         // Name of the attribute that will be matched
            true,              // Apply dialect prefix to attribute name
            PRECEDENCE,        // Precedence (inside dialect's precedence)
            true);             // Remove the matched attribute afterwards
    }

    /**
     * Performs the actual task of the processor. This will use quack data to construct an Url path.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doProcess(final ITemplateContext context, final IProcessableElementTag tag,
            final AttributeName attributeName, final String attributeValue,
            final IElementTagStructureHandler structureHandler) {
        IEngineConfiguration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
        IStandardExpressionParser parser = StandardExpressions.getExpressionParser(configuration);
        IStandardExpression expression = parser.parseExpression(context, attributeValue);

        Quack quack = (Quack)expression.execute(context);
        String url = QuackManager.buildUrlPath(quack);

        structureHandler.setAttribute("href", applicationProperties.getFrontendBaseUrl() + url);
    }
}
```

custom dialect:

```
public class XContDialect extends AbstractProcessorDialect implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    /**
     * Constructor that will define the name of the Dialect.
     */
    public XConDialect() {
        super("XConsult Dialect", "xc", 1000);
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the dialect's processors.
     *
     * Note the dialect prefix is passed here because, although "xc" is set to be the dialect's prefix in the
     * constructor, that only works as a default, and at engine configuration time the user might have chosen
     * a different prefix to be used.
     */
    public Set<IProcessor> getProcessors(final String dialectPrefix) {
        final Set<IProcessor> processors = new HashSet<IProcessor>();

        QuackUrlAttributeTagProcessor processor = new QuackUrlAttributeTagProcessor(dialectPrefix);
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        factory.autowireBean(processor);

        processors.add(processor);
        return processors;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

with this I can add attributes in the html template as follows:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:xc="http://www.example.de">

 <link rel="canonical" xc:quackToHref="${quack}" />
```

which sets the href-attribute correctly. Now the ld+json script looks as follows:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">

    /*<![CDATA[*/

    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@graph": [
        {
          "@type": "Article",
          "url": "[[xc:quackToHref="${quack}"]]",
          "isPartOf": { "@id": "test" },
          "author": {
            "name": "[[${article.nickname}]]",
            "@id": "https://example.de/profile/[[${article.authorId}]]"
          },          
        },
       
        ]
      }

    /*]]>*/

  </script>
```

What throws the error:

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as expression: "xc:quackToHref="${quack}" (template: "articlequack" - line 38, col 22)
```

Apparently, it is not possible to call the custom processor inside the script. Does anyone know how to get the url inside CDATA?

Comment: Can you tell what dependency are you using for Quack please? I'm in the way of solving this?

Comment: The only working solution, I found so far is calling the service directly by: `https://mysite.de[[${T(de.my.service.QuackManager).buildUrlPath(quack)}]]`. I think I tried around 1k combinations of characters, I just didn't find a way to call the method `quackToHref` inside javascript or ld+json respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use attributes in [textual template modes](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#textual-syntax), the syntax should look like this:

```
[# xc:quackToHref="${quack}" /]
```

Comment: This is not parsed, but just returns the string [# xc:quackToHref="${quack}" /] in the json. xc:quackToHref is just parsed when using in html-tags, but not inside the script

Comment: Does it work if you add th:inline="javascript" to your script tag? `<script type="application/ld+json" th:inline="javascript">`?

Comment: In this case I just get no return value (`@id": ,`) and also can't see that the method is called in my java log. So might it be that I need to set up another processer for CDATA as described here https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/extendingthymeleaf.html#other-processors

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<script type="application/ld+json">

    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@graph": [
        {
          "@type": "Article",
          "url": "[[${applicationProperties.frontendBaseUrl}]]${quack}", 
          "isPartOf": { "@id": "test" },
          "author": {
            "name": "[[${article.nickname}]]",
            "@id": "https://example.de/profile/[[${article.authorId}]]"
          }         
        }
      ]
    }

   

</script>
```

- Ensure that the applicationProperties.frontendBaseUrl variable is accessible where you are using it in the template.
- Use Thymeleaf Expressions Correctly: Check that you are using Thymeleaf expressions correctly within the template, such as `[[...]]` or `${...}.`

try this and let me know if not solved comment here..

Comment: This returns  "console.log(<!DOCTYPE HTML>" an throws the following error   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/articlequack.html]")] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getFrontendBaseUrl() on null context object`

Answer (score -2):

To use a custom Thymeleaf dialect in an HTML template, you need to include the dialect in your project, configure it, and then use it in your HTML file. Here are the steps to call a custom Thymeleaf dialect in your HTML script:

1. Add the custom dialect to your project:

   - First, you need to create a custom Thymeleaf dialect by implementing the `org.thymeleaf.dialect.IDialect` interface. This involves defining your own processors, attributes, or tags that the dialect will handle.
2. Configure Thymeleaf to use the custom dialect:

   - In your project configuration (e.g., Spring Boot application), you can configure Thymeleaf to include your custom dialect. Here's an example of how to configure Thymeleaf with a custom dialect in a Spring Boot application's `application.properties` or `application.yml` file:

   ```
   spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
   spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
   spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
   spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
   spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
   spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
   spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type=text/html
   spring.thymeleaf.servlet.cache=true
   spring.thymeleaf.servlet.order=1
   spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
   spring.thymeleaf.template-resolver-order=1
   spring.thymeleaf.cache-names=cache
   spring.thymeleaf.dialects.custom-dialect=your.package.CustomDialect
   ```

   In this example, you configure the Thymeleaf dialect by specifying the package and class name of your custom dialect.
3. Use the custom dialect in your HTML templates:

   - In your HTML templates, you can now use the custom dialect's features. For example, if your custom dialect adds a custom attribute or tag, you can use it as follows:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:custom="http://www.example.com/thymeleaf-custom-dialect">
   <head>
       <title>Custom Dialect Example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div custom:yourAttribute="someValue">Custom Dialect Attribute</div>
       <custom:customTag>Custom Dialect Tag</custom:customTag>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   Replace `http://www.example.com/thymeleaf-custom-dialect` with the namespace URI of your custom dialect.
4. Build and run your application:

   - After configuring and using the custom dialect in your HTML templates, build and run your application. The custom dialect's functionality will be applied to the Thymeleaf templates during rendering.

Ensure that your custom dialect is properly implemented and registered in your application for it to work as expected. Also, make sure that you use the correct namespace and syntax in your HTML templates to invoke the custom dialect's features.